# Why i can't update a realmObject that has a realmList inside it ? (I get an error)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, realm, realm-list

I want to update a RealmObject that contains RealmList and I faced this error : (look at the images)

So why I faced this error? and what's the solution?

Also why RealmObject has duplicate parameters (image 2)

My code and the error are below

InvoiceModel :

```
open class PurchaseDatabase : RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    var id: Int? = 0
    var date: String? = ""
    var supplier: String? = ""
    var products: RealmList<ProductBuyModel> = realmListOf()
    var totalPrice: Int? = 0
    var paymentMethod: String? = ""
    var paymentPrice: Int? = 0
    var restPrice: Int? = 0
}
```

Error :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.bakirdev.gestiondestock, PID: 9705
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot import an outdated object. Use findLatest(object) to find an 
up-to-date version of the object in the given context before importing it.

at io.realm.kotlin.internal.RealmObjectListOperator.insert(RealmListInternal.k:370)
at io.realm.kotlin.internal.ListOperator$DefaultImpls.insertAll(RealmListInternal.kt:202)
at io.realm.kotlin.internal.BaseRealmObjectListOperator.insertAll(RealmListInternal.kt:258)
at com.bakirdev.gestiondestock.ui.purchases.PurchaseDatabase.setProducts(PurchaseDatabase.kt:150)
at com.bakirdev.gestiondestock.ui.purchases.AddNewInvoice$initListenerEdit$2$1.invoke(AddNewInvoice.kt:168)
at com.bakirdev.gestiondestock.ui.purchases.AddNewInvoice$initListenerEdit$2$1.invoke(AddNewInvoice.kt:162)
at io.realm.kotlin.internal.SuspendableWriter$write$2.invokeSuspend(SuspendableWriter.kt:109)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

My Code :

```
           var invoiceModel: PurchaseDatabase? = purchasesList[position]

            realm.writeBlocking {
                // fetch a frog from the realm by primary key
                invoiceModel = this.query<PurchaseDatabase>("id == ${model.id}").first().find()
                // modify the frog's age in the write transaction to persist the new age to the realm
                invoiceModel?.supplier = purchasesSupplier
                invoiceModel?.products?.clear()
                invoiceModel?.products = products
                invoiceModel?.totalPrice = totalPrice
                invoiceModel?.paymentMethod = paymentMethod
                invoiceModel?.paymentPrice = purchasesPaymentPrice.trim().toInt()
                invoiceModel?.restPrice = purchasesRestPrice.trim().toInt()
            }
            Purchases.invoiceModel = invoiceModel
            val returnedValue = Intent().apply {
                putExtra("position", position)
            }
            setResult(RESULT_OK, returnedValue)
            finish()
```

[image: Duplicate parameters]

Comment: Please copy/paste your code and error message here as text, not a screenshot.

Comment: Ok i'll do it, sorry for that

Comment: The code is a bit vague - why is `invoiceModel` being used like that? `var invoiceModel:...= purchasesList` and then `invoiceModel = this.query`? And what's the expected result here `Purchases.invoiceModel = invoiceModel`?

Comment: I assign "invoiceModel" to "purchasesList" to avoid nullable 
When I finish updating I edit the list on other activity

Comment: Please re-read my comment. Why is invoiceModel assigned a value and then it's assigned a different value? Also, as mentioned above, please post errors as text, not images. It's also a good idea to include models in questions so we know what the intended look of the object should be,

Comment: I assign invoiceModel a value to avoid nullable value when I send value (returnedValue)

Comment: I edit the code (add invoiceModel)